# Trying to mute an entire voice channel with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm pretty new to python and searched all over https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and didn't find any option like that.
can someone write out a code for me?
that's what I've done:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot is ready!')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to generate a list of all users in that voice channel, then go through a for loop muting each one.

`channel.members` will return a list of all members in the voice channel (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20members#discord.VoiceChannel.members)